# psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence

Tags: python, amazon-s3, psycopg2

Here's what I am trying to do. I am trying to input an .csv file to be input into postgres database. I am using psycopg2 and cur_copy_export to do this. However, i'm hit with the error as below. What should i do to overcome this error?

Thanks in Advance

Error:

```
    cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=myfile)
    psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xdf 0x65
    CONTEXT:  COPY agents, line 1117
```

My code as below:

```
//open file from Amazon S3 Bucket
opener = urllib.URLopener()
myurl=("Amazon S3 bucket URL" + srcbucketid + "/" + file_name)
myfile=opener.open(myurl)   

copy_sql = """ COPY agents (
UniqueId,
Code,
CountryCode,
DefaultCommissionRate,
ReportingName)
FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER as ',' QUOTE '\b' NULL AS ''"""

cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=myfile)
```

My database encoding is in "UTF8" format. I cannot change it as its a production database for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy_source = {'Bucket': srcbucketid, 'Key': file_name}
client.copy(copy_source, srcbucketid, 'tmp/{}'.format(file_name))
key = ('s3://'+srcbucketid+'tmp/'+file_name)
print(key)
BLOCKSIZE = 1024*1024
with s3.open('s3://'+srcbucketid+'/'+file_name, 'rb') as inf:
    with s3.open('s3://'+srcbucketid+'/tmp/'+file_name, 'wb') as ouf:
        while True:
            data = inf.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not data: break
            converted = data.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8')
            ouf.write(converted)
```